# How to implement "safe navigation"-compatible "null object pattern"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

I like the Null Object Pattern, e.g.

```rb
class NullAddress
  def details; "No address entered yet";  end

  def blank?;   true; end
  def present?; false; end
  def nil?;     true; end
end

address = NullAddress.new
```

But I have no idea (nor found something) how to make this `&.`-compatible:

```
address&.city
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `city' for #<NullAddress:0x000055d3bbdeb7e8>
```

Unfortunately Safe Navigation is widely used in our application, so I have to keep that in mind when implementing Null Object Pattern.

I've tried with extending NullObject. But this doesn't raise any NoMethodError at all:

```
address.foo_is_no_method
#=> nil
```

Any hints?

Comment: I don't really think this is possible. The `&.` operator will prevent a NoMethodError no matter what the object its called on is.

Answer (score 1):

Safe navigation operator is part of ruby's grammar. It's not operator which you can implement as method in your code.

If you still want to get rid of `NoMethodError` then you can use

```rb
def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
  nil
end
```

but this is just a hack.

There can be other consequences of this implementation when you call other methods which you expect theme on address class but because of `method_missing` you get `nil` always.

like `address.location` will return `nil` which supposed to throw `NoMethodError`